# SELECT avg(rate) FROM ratings WHERE sid=1 in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to implement equivalent of this SQL command in MongoDB?

```
SELECT avg(rate) FROM ratings WHERE sid=1
```

No need to grouping.

Comment: Have you seen the answer I posted? It would be best to mark as accepted, if it solves your issue. Otherwise, this question just remains open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is [**`aggregation`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) framework in mongodb where you can make a pipeline of stages you want for query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    {
        $match: {
            "sid": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: avg(rate): {
            $avg: "$rate"
        }
    }

])
```

As you know in `sql` query `where` part is applied first that's why we've place `$match` pipeline at first. [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in mongodb is somehow equivalent to `where` i SQL and there is [**`$avg`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) in mongodb which works the same as `AVG` in `SQL`

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: This is an incorrect aggregation. The `avg(rate)` following `$project` is incorrect - it should just be a named variable (e.g. `avgRate`). Further: `$project` is the wrong pipeline element: it is going to return one document per entry matching `sid==1` - it's going to create an average of all the values in a single document (that is, just one document), and then emit one row per matching document. The correct pipeline element is `$group` (as shown in the answer I posted).

Comment: Ohk.  Yeah you're right.  but isn't that what `select ....` would produce  ? a single row ?@DavidMakogon\

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - `select` is returning a single aggregation row in sql (the average of all `rate` values across all rows with `sid=1`). For MongoDB, the aggregation (averaging) needs to take place over the set of grouped elements (grouped by the same `sid` val), taking the average of the `rate` element across all of the grouped documents. And *that* returns a single document (or more, if the `$match` clause is removed or expanded). `$project`, on the other hand, will just return you every single document with `sid=1`, along with its `rate` value. And that is not equivalent to the sql statement.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying and adding to my knowledge :)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, use `$avg` within the `$group` aggregation pipeline element. Basic pipeline flow:

- match on `sid=1` (your `WHERE` clause)
- group by `sid` (there's only one sid to group by at this point, because the others are filtered out via match), and generate an average within the group'd content

Your pipeline would look something like:

```
db.rates.aggregate(
 [
   { $match: {"sid":1}}, 
   { $group: { _id: "$sid", rateAvg: {$avg:  "$rate" } }}
 ])
```